# Field picker for the data tables list pages

Tags: laravel, datatable, laravel-backpack

I want to develop a field picker like below images for below requirements.

[image]
[image]

- Page opens with a default option.
- User can change fields around and save as default.
- Default is **remembered** next time the view opens for that user.

So anyone know about this. Guide me to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this using show or hide columns dynamically option in Datatable. Below attached Datatable link is very useful. [show or hide columns dynamically in Datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html)